# Docraptor PDF: How to avoid displaying header in 2nd Page

Tags: php, pdf, princexml

Im generating PDFs using docraptor API and my pdfs can have multiple pages. I have set the header image for the pdf but it appears on all pages. I need the header in the first page only.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not just set it as normal content at the start of the document, not as a header which is repeated on each page?

Answer (score 2):

Lecstor's answer will definitely work in this case, but it's possible to have vary headers on different pages.

Full documentation is available on Prince (DocRaptor's PDF renderer) [Named Pages](http://www.princexml.com/doc/advanced-paged/#named-pages) section, but it should look roughly like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
@page has-header {
  @top {
    content: "This is header of text";
  }
}

.first-page {
  page: has-header; 
  /* all content within .first-page will use the above @page styling */
}
</style>

<div class="first-page">
  Put first page content here
</div>

<p>Rest of content will not have a header.</p>
```

That pattern can be repeated. Different named pages can have different headers, different margins, different landscape/portrait modes, sizes, etc..

Comment: Thank you. This was also very helpful as the requirement changed. The succeeding pages will have different header from the first page.